# How to do URL rewrite in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a web application, ex: 'http://MySite.in' of my own and needs to connect it to other sites, ex: twitter. The requirement is that if clicked link for Twitter in my web application, after redirecting to twitter client need to see the url as http://MySite.in/twitter/page.aspx. If moved to section 'Tweets' in twitter, then url need to be rewitten as http://MySite.in/twitter/Tweets/page.aspx. I tried creating rewrite rule in IIS. But the site is asking for credentials again and again. Anybody have an idea on this?

Comment: Why would you want to trick people into thinking they're still on your site when they're actually on twitter?

Comment: Its my client's requirement. They want it like that only.

Answer (score 0):

A simple advice: Do not play with SharePoint URL Rewriting.